# Xcode8 folder references, env vars?

Tags: build, xcode8

I have my own library and imported into Xcode as references (blue folders), surprised (not really) Xcode chokes and can't find the classes.

The lib is linked relative to the group. {../../../libr1/swift/3.01}

I'm trying to hack this code, which I blatantly swiped from here http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2012/10/21/xcode-groups-vs-folder-references/

```
/bin/sh
    find -L ${SRCROOT}// -type f -not -name “.*” -not -name “`basename ${INFOPLIST_FILE}`” | xargs -t -I {} cp {} ${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/{}
```

when I check the build folders 'Objects-normal/x86_64' none of the files are copied or compiled.  can anyone help with this?

Comment: Please describe the actual issue more detailed "Xcode chokes and can't find the classes. "

Comment: it's pretty much just like that. i have a file called logAssert.swift with a  'public func myLog{}'  at every place where it is called, Xcode chokes and throws up an error saying the function is undefined and wants to replace it with Log.  however in the left side of the IDE, the file is visable and can be edited.  this is a problem with Xcode not copying and compiling the source files even though i have explicitly told it to do so. it appears Xcode is not converting soft links into hard links or i don't have the correct env vars defined?  hard linking may or may not work for folder refences

Comment: OK. So technically you do not have your own library, but a folder with source files you want to use. In this case make sure your .swift files are in "Compile Sources". If you did, maybe edit your question with more details what exactly you did  already "i have explicitly told it to do so" and what the exact error is. Otherwise it's difficult to help.

Comment: ok i'll edit question, i do have my own library there's just no decent fortran/c/asm API and I really don't want to rewrite my code in for gpu until i can benchmark swift otherwise I'll port my code.  i expect mediocre python type results but that might be ok.  But I'm already not happy with Xcode, my makefile can compile for any gcc, clang flavors on *nix or linux but apple can't make a decent IDE that knows how to handle softlinks, incredible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a bug in xcode 8.2 and now 8.2.1 in which it does not execute scripts that are located in the schemes.

i ran tests in build and run schemes, pre and post action, all failed.

```
 /bin/bash
echo "//  Application version generated at build time." > ${PROJECT}/version.swift
```

the initial script will work but it needs to be placed in 'Build Phases' BEFORE 'Compile Sources' obviously

If you check and set the env vars from here

"https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW24"

you can squeeze more performance out of your app.  i would rather have my bash script do things than Xcode.